# FxCop + MVP: "Properties should not be write only"

Tags: interface, mvp, fxcop

Suppose I'm implementing an MVP pattern and I have a view interface as such:

```
interface IView {

    string SuperRadString { set; }
}
```

There's no reason for the presenter to ever need to retrieve this string from the view, so can I safely ignore this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, yes...

However, semantically it would make more sense to have a method for setting the value than a "black hole property".